# Importing an external library into nodejs vm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a nodejs library that allows for the user to write their own JS code which will be executed. For example:

```
var MyJournal = Yurnell.newJournal();

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  MyJournal.description = "my first description"

  // deployment steps
  deployer.deploy(MyJournal)
};
```

This eventually gets called using [nodejs VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)

```
var script = vm.createScript(fileWithFrontend.content, file);
script.runInNewContext(context);
```

Passing in the Yurnell and deployer object via the context parameter.

My question is whether there is a way for the user to also import their own libraries into the script? and if so where in users path would the script look for the library?

For example in their code it would be useful for them to do something like `var moment = require('moment');` and format the dates using that library also.

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at the VM2 npm package and this if it can help you in any way. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2

Comment: this if it can -> see if it can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can arbitrary add libraries and custom class or function as well by doing this

Here `vmObjectScript` is function or script written by user

```
const vmObject = {
  _,
  moment,
  axios,
  BadRequestError,
  sftpConnection,
  https,
  crypto,
  employeeDataClass
};
await vm.createContext(vmObject);
await vm.runInContext(vmObjectScript, vmObject);
```

Here one thing user don;t have to import javascript library
it will available already in code to use it